# Why did I get No Responding window when calling cv2.imshow() in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Whenever I run the code below in Jupyter notebook, A window pops out and becomes No Reponding. What I was doing is to convert the image into HSV color space.

```py
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("lena.png", 1)
#cv2.imshow("1", im)
#cv2.waitKey()

im_HSV=[]
im_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow("HSV", im_HSV)
```

However, the code runs perfectly on spyder.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of solving this issue,

A) Using matplotlib :

```py
%matplotlib inline
#The line above is necesary to show Matplotlib's plots inside a Jupyter Notebook

import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Import image
image = cv2.imread("input_path")

#Convert to HSV
im_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#Show the image with matplotlib
plt.imshow(im_HSV)
plt.show()
```

The other way is
B) Using the opencv's waitkey function

```py
import cv2

#Import image
image = cv2.imread("input_path")

#Convert to HSV
im_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow(im_HSV,"HSV")
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyWindows()
```

Comment: second example will show nothing. it's missing an `imshow`.

Comment: Yes you are right will update it, thanks!

Comment: aaand that's the wrong order of arguments

Comment: `destroyWindows()` is invalid name. Valid names is `destroyAllWindows()` and `destroyWindow()`